# Does the albedo of a photovoltaic cell correlate with its load?

Tags: visible-light, electric-circuits, solar-cells

Exactly what the title says. Since solar panels convert (to my understanding) visible light into electricity, will a solar panel under load appear visually darker compared to a solar panel under no load?

Better phrasing: Does the albedo of a photovoltaic cell correlate with its load?

Comment: Do you insist on "visually" or would it suffice to calculate the total number of photons either reflected or emitted, regardless of wavelength?

Comment: If it isn't visible to the human eye, that's okay. I was just wondering if they would be lighter, even on an imperceptible level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "regular" (silicon-based) solar panels, I believe the answer is no.  Silicon is an [indirect band gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_and_indirect_band_gaps) material.  Recombination rarely releases photons, so an increase in conduction band electrons does not make the material glow.  Likewise, an increase in valence band electrons does not make the material darker.

Now if you had something like a GaAs panel, I'd be less certain.  I suspect that it would be hard to see it visibly, but it's very possible that the material would emit significantly more recombination photons when under no load than when the cell is nearly short circuited.

Comment: Does the material need to glow though to satisfy OP's criteria? Could it just not reflect as much light?

Comment: I think the next sentence mentions that the material shouldn't be darker when load is applied.  I couldn't find any models for the absorption coefficient of silicon PV that suggested it depended on either cell voltage or cell current.

Comment: I was thinking that if the PV cell is saturated with charge (I don't know if that's the right term), would it simply not be able to absorb as much visible light? Would it be less absorbent, making it appear lighter?

Comment: That's a reasonable assumption for a direct band gap material.  But for silicon, I don't think so.  Energy production is a two step process in that material and the absorptive first step doesn't seem to depend on the charge state.  That energy will just get turned into heat if there are no carriers available.